# How to query BackLog items. Filter by childs state

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

How to  create query in TFS 2013 for Backlog items, which have all tasks in Done state except task with name "Test it".

To clarify, I'm looking for Backlog item 1 from picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest think you can have is using query for "Work Items and Direct link" that can give you an *approximation* of what you need. You are basically asking TFS to return only PBI that have not child tasks with a specific condition.

This query will incorrectly returns PBI that have all child tasks in done state, even if they have no task with the text "test it" in the title. Probably when all child Tasks are completed you will set PBI state to "done", so you can filter out from the query with removing PBI with state "done".

If you really, really need to have this kind of information, probably the best approach is using API or REST call, using a base query to return all PBI with a Child Task with "test it" not in "done" state, loading Everything and then do some further filtering with complex conditions in your tool.

I agree with Martin that it is a better solution to reduce the distance between testing and developing team maximizing communication.

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The closest you Can get is to have PBI where the test task is open. Can't you just look down the list of things on the sprint backlog and identify your tasks in seconds?

If you are a tester then you should be working closely with the rest of the development team and know what if ready to test. If you don't know without looking in TFS then you have have a later organisational problem.